# WCF over IIS through load balancer reports wrong base address

Tags: wcf, iis, https

I'm trying to launch a WCF service over SSL on IIS 6 through a load balancer.  My initial problem was an obvious and pretty well discussed one - the address shown on the WSDL page pointed to https://SERVERNAME/WebServices/mydomainws.svc instead of www.mydomain.com.  The answer to this problem is to add a host header value in IIS.  I did that and it worked... sort of.  I now get **http**://www.mydomain.com/WebServices/mydomainws.svc when viewing the wsdl in a browser.  If I click on that link (the non-ssl link) I get a service definition that again references the server name.

The next oft recommended remedy is to use [WCF Extras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/) which provides an extension that allows you to specify a base address.  But setting that config entry only updated the soap12:address.  The EndPointReference address is still using the machine name.

To summarize: WSDL as viewed in web browser at https://www.mydomain.com/WebServices/mydomainws.svc:  **http**://www.mydomain.com/WebServices/mydomainws.scv

Clicking the above link brings me to an actual wsdl file with the following service entry:

**https://ServerName/WebServices/mydomainws.svc**

My server config file has the following serviceModel entries:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="TransportSecurity">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="mydomain.ws.mydomainws" behaviorConfiguration="mydomainwsBehavior">
            <!-- Service Endpoints -->
            <endpoint address="" **behaviorConfiguration="CorrectEndPoint"** binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="mydomain.ws.Imydomainws"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" **behaviorConfiguration="CorrectEndPoint"** binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="mydomainwsBehavior">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            **<behavior name="CorrectEndPoint">
                <wsdlExtensions location="https://www.mydomain.com/WebServices/mydomainws.svc" singleFile="true"/>
            </behavior>**
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="wsdlExtensions" type="WCFExtras.Wsdl.WsdlExtensionsConfig, WCFExtras, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>

</system.serviceModel>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks,
George

Comment: Worth noting: the problem went away when I switched from wsHttpBinding to basicHttpBinding.  I had to do this anyway as my caller is on .net 2.0 and cannot consume a wsHttpBinding service.  I believe I still need the reference to the WCF Extras extension.

Answer (score 7):

This should be handeled by new behavior [useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress](http://zamd.net/2010/01/14/using-request-headers-for-metadata-address/). Try to add this to your service behavior:

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="LoadBalancedBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts>
          <add scheme="http" port="80" />
          <add scheme="https" port="443" />
        </defaultPorts>
      </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>

      <!-- Other service behaviors as necesary -->

    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

This behavior is availabel in WCF 4.0 and should be available as KB for WCF 3.x.

Comment: I've read up on this and it appears that it *should* solve my problem.  I am running WCF 4.0 but unfortunately adding the tag had no impact.

Comment: @GeorgeBarker: Did you ever get this solved? I am having the same issue. The WSDL always generates addresses with HTTP, not HTTPS. I have also tried adding the new useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress behaviour and it made no difference...

Comment: @JTech: very late note, primarily for benefit of others like us: If this fix appears to do nothing, it is possible that the proxy/load balancer is also rewriting the request headers. you may test the service directly on the IIS host, bypassing the proxy to confirm this. For an Apache proxy, I had to add a **ProxyPreserveHost** directive to the configuration.

Comment: I was able to add this, and then in the WCF test client, edit the generated config to point to https, and further edit it to do transport security.  You can also effectively do the same in whatever client.  This worked for my scenario; I'm not sure if it would work for everyone's.  We were moving from certs on the boxes to certs on BigIp.